# Flutter: In ReorderableListView: Cannot find the correct Provider<...> when dragging

Tags: flutter, dart

I have my theme class that I hang in the widget tree using `Provider`:

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: Provider<AppControlsThemeData>(
    create: (_) => ...,
    child: ...
  ),
);
```

Then somewhere below I read it with

```dart
final themeData = Provider.of<AppControlsThemeData>(context);
```

It works alright until I try to use this lookup in `ReorderableListView`. When I drag the widget that does the lookup, it fails to find the provider:

[image]

How do I hang some object in the widget tree so that its lookup works while dragging? I hang it as far as it is reasonable -- right under the `Scaffold`. Looks like this draggable widget gets detached from my screen's tree and I cannot control what is above it in its new tree.

Comment: It is a recognized bug in Flutter: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88570
A temporary workaround is to wrap each item with a copy of the provider.